# Accesing a publicly shared Google calendar

Tags: jquery, google-api

I have for the last few days been trying to figure out how to pull calendar data from one of my Google user's calendar using only jQuery in a simple HTML web page but have not reached the solution I'm in need of.

The calendar is shared publicly ("Make this calendar public" is checked on the calendar settings).

Here are the solutions I've attempted.

### Solution 1

I looked at the data coming from the feed, which can be accessed in this manner: `http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/{calendar-id-here}/public/basic?alt=json`.  This solution, while it works, does not provide enough information about individual events.  For example, events do not have start date/time and end date/time data.  Well, they do but its buried in strings, and I'd rather not scrape the strings for dates and times.

### Solution 2

I created a project in Google Console along with a simple API key, then tried a few examples around the Internet to get this code:

```
gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3')
    .then(function () {
        return gapi.client.setApiKey(apikey);
    })
    .then(function () {
        return gapi.client.calendar.calendars.get({calendarId: '{calendarId-here}'});
    })
    .then(function () {
        console.log('Worked!');
    }, function () {
        console.log('It failed!');
    });
```

This code kept returning a 401 Unauthorized response.

### Solution 3

The final solution was to try accessing it using OAuth.  After setting up the correct refers and so forth, this solution works but it requires the visitor to sign into Google for the API to function.

**My question, then**: is it even possible to anonymously access a publicly shared Google user's calendar and if so, what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this before but with YouTube and Ajax.  It's a bit hacky but it got the job done.  First you'll need the raw RSS, [apparently you can get it](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/zA1Ek37WUnI).  Then use Ajax with dataType: xml to grab the XML from the feed.  From there, it'll depend on how the data structure but the hard part would be over at that point.  [Here's my post about handling YouTube.](http://www.schema.tc/2014/02/is-it-live.html)